Old sci-fi movie on another planet with an evil robot (partly organic) chasing protagonists through a laboratory
A decade (or even longer) ago, I watched a sci-fi movie (on TV), which was set on another planet. There was a scene, where a terrifying robot (it was in parts organic; its body was humanoid, but its neck was only like a stick and its head looked only like a (red) brain with short binoculars in front) was chasing the protagonists through a laboratory. The protagonists were hiding below the steel grids of the laboratory floor.
I cannot remember the name of the movie.

Sounds to me like Saturn 3 (1980).  A mostly humanoid robot, "Hector", chases Farrah Fawcett and Kirk Douglass through a lab in the astroid belts of Saturn.  The robot's head was just a camera on top of some small arms and there was a small red light on the top.

Thank you very much! It's indeed 'Saturn 3' (watched a scene on youtube). I think i got the 'brain' part wrong in my memories :)
